# xp_CmdShell , write image only to location where SQL Server is hosted..not to server(Location) i wants

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using xp_CmdShell in an sp to write an image to a location like C:\ImageUpload. This works absolutely fine on the server location where SQL Server is hosted. I know this may be typical behaviour.

One of my clients however is having his own server where databases are hosted. He needs to write the image on another server location.

Below is part of my SQL sp. It normally works fine, but in the case above I want to write the image to another server location.

```
SET @strOutputFilePath = C:/ImageUpload

-- Get Final Path
SET   @strOutputFilePath = @strOutputFilePath + @strFilename
PRINT @strOutputFilePath -- path will be like C:\ImageUpload\NameofFile
SET   @strSql = 'BCP "set fmtonly off SELECT BlobImage FROM dbo.TblImage where ID = ' + CAST(@id AS VARCHAR(10)) +''
                    + '" QUERYOUT ' + '"' +@strOutputFilePath+ '"' + ' -T -f C:\Test\testblob.fmt -S"' + @@SERVERNAME + '"'
PRINT @strSql  
EXEC  @RC = master.dbo.xp_CmdShell @strSql
PRINT @RC
```

How can I specify the particular server location so that the image can be written to that folder and not the one where SQL Server is hosted?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a few things.

1. update the server to use UNC path.  so the reference to the location
   should read \\ServerName\FileShare\File.txt rather and
   Drive:\Directory\File.txt.
2. If the SQL server was installed correctly, and securely, the account
   that xp_cmdshell uses might not have permissions.  so either allow
   the service account permissions to the shared folder OR (the more
   secure method) setup a `PROXY` account for xp_cmdshell.  You can find the account that xp_cmdshell uses by having it issue the command `whoami`

Comment: ##ServerName when i use... it uses the server location where database is installed like Server1 C folder but i want Server2 C folder....

Comment: In the example the \\ServerName should be the destination server. You can use the Admin share as well if you're not setting up network shares.  so if your SQL Server is SRV1 but your file share is SRV2 you would use \\SRV2\c$\Folder\...